# Error accessing the rapidAPI on deploying the app

Tags: next.js, authorization, vercel, rapidapi

I have subscribed to an API from RapidAPI. It worked fine locally, but after deploying the next application on to Vercel it's not working.

The code for API call:

```
export const compileCode= async ( payload )=>{
const options = {
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'https://judge0-ce.p.rapidapi.com/submissions',
    params: {
      base64_encoded: 'true',
      fields: '*'
    },
    headers: {
      'content-type': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'X-RapidAPI-Key': process.env.JUDGE0_API,
      'X-RapidAPI-Host': 'judge0-ce.p.rapidapi.com'
    },
    data: payload
  };
  
try{
    const {data}= await axios.request(options)
    return data
} catch(error){
    console.log(error)
    alert("Something went wrong => "+ error)
}}
```

This is the error message:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 ()
```